# Shortcut for display sub class method in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Say I have one base class, and serveral sub class will override the method f() in the base class. I move mouse on the method f() in base class, is there any shortcut to show me the methods in its subclasses. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate > Implementations (Ctrl + Alt + B in default keymap for Windows/Linux, Cmd + Alt + B for Mac) will show you the methods that either override or implement (if the method is in a interface, not class) the currently selected method.